# Delivery geolocations query

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I have the below MySQL query that does exactly what I need, but I am sure there are better queries that do the same thing.

If you see something very ugly or bad and have any suggestions, I will be very glad to hear them.

```
SELECT c.`ID_COURIER`, c.`NAME`,
    c.`NICKNAME`, c.`AREA_CODE`, 
    c.`PHONE_NUMBER`, d.`ID_DELIVERY`, 
    d.`DESCRIPTION`, d.`START_DATE`, 
    d.`END_DATE`, d.`CANCELED`, 
    r.`LAT`, r.`LNG`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ID_ORDER`) FROM `ORDERS` WHERE `ID_DELIVERY` = d.`ID_DELIVERY` AND `DELIVERY_DATE` IS NULL AND `CANCELED` = false) as REMAINING_ORDERS 
FROM `COURIER` as c 
    LEFT JOIN `DELIVERY` as d USING (`ID_COURIER`) 
    LEFT JOIN `GEOLOCATIONS` as r ON r.`ID_DELIVERY` = d.`ID_DELIVERY` 
WHERE c.`ID_COMPANY` = ? AND c.`DISABLED` = false
    AND (
        CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(`START_DATE`) 
                       FROM `DELIVERY` 
                       WHERE `ID_COURIER` = c.`ID_COURIER`) 
                 IS NULL THEN d.`START_DATE` IS NULL 
                 ELSE d.`START_DATE` = (SELECT MAX(`START_DATE`) 
                                        FROM `DELIVERY` 
                                        WHERE `ID_COURIER` = c.`ID_COURIER`) 
            END )
    AND (
        CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(`ID_GEOLOCATION`) 
                       FROM `GEOLOCATIONS` 
                       WHERE `ID_DELIVERY` = d.`ID_DELIVERY`) 
                     IS NULL THEN r.`ID_GEOLOCATION` IS NULL
                   ELSE r.`ID_GEOLOCATION` = (SELECT MAX(`ID_GEOLOCATION`) 
                                               FROM `GEOLOCATIONS` 
                                               WHERE `ID_DELIVERY` = d.`ID_DELIVERY`)
            END)
GROUP BY c.`ID_COURIER`
ORDER BY d.`START_DATE` DESC
```

Comment: If you would like help with an SQL performance issue, please post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.

Comment: Some context regarding database structure and example rows in the table along with example results from the query would be helpful.

Comment: I agree more context would help tremendously. You have a lot of nested subquries and aggregate functions within them and I could see that causing issues, I would try to avoid that as much as you can. I'll try and come up with an answer shortly based on what you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top to bottom, here we go.

- `COUNT(DISTINCT ID_ORDER)`

  This `DISTINCT` aggregation seems superfluous, if `ID_ORDER` is a true identity column then there should not be duplicates. This will improve performance.
- `LEFT JOIN DELIVERY AS d USING (ID_COURIER)`

  I'm not a big fan of the `USING` keyword as I find it ambiguous. Agreed it's a useful shorthand but to the next person going back to read your code they would have to go and check that both tables have a `ID_COURIER` column. Plus if one of the columns got renamed at any point it would be more difficult to find the bug.

  My suggestion:

  ```
  LEFT JOIN `DELIVERY` AS d ON c.ID_DELIVERY = d.ID_DELIVERY
  ```
- `WHERE c.ID_COMPANY = ?`

  This doesn't seem to have any purpose I'm sure you could take it out with no difference.
- `CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(START_DATE)` and the rest of the statement.

  This I find very unusual and not optimal for performance. I'm not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do but I'll give it my best shot. You may want to instead build this into your select. Here is what I suggest for the complete script. I made some edits to the layout to make it easier to read. If I misunderstood the intention of your `CASE` statements let me know and I can revise.

```
SELECT     
    c.ID_COURIER,     
    c.NAME,
    c.NICKNAME, 
    c.AREA_CODE, 
    c.PHONE_NUMBER, 
-- This will return NULL if ID_GEOLOCATION is NULL
    (SELECT MAX(ID_GEOLOCATION) FROM GEOLOCATIONS) AS 'ID_GEOLOCATION',
    d.DESCRIPTION,     
-- This will return NULL if START_DATE is NULL
    (SELECT MAX(START_DATE) FROM ORDERS) AS 'START_DATE',
    d.END_DATE,
    d.CANCELED,
    r.LAT, 
    r.LNG, 
-- Subquery JOIN moved to FROM and WHERE statements
    COUNT(ID_ORDER) AS 'REMAINING ORDERS'   
FROM COURIER AS c 
    LEFT JOIN DELIVERY AS d ON c.ID_DELIVERY = d.ID_DELIVERY
    LEFT JOIN GEOLOCATIONS AS r ON r.ID_DELIVERY = d.ID_DELIVERY 
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS AS o ON d.ID_DELIVERY = o.ID_DELIVERY
WHERE c.DISABLED = false
AND o.DELIVERY_DATE IS NULL AND o.CANCELED = false
GROUP BY c.ID_COURIER
ORDER BY d.START_DATE DESC;
```